# cant download meteor.js on windows

Tags: web, meteor, windows-10, vpn, chocolatey

I try to download meteor.js on my laptop (windows10 46X)
I get this message and I am from sudan and use protonVPN.

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> choco install meteor
Chocolatey v1.0.0
Installing the following packages:
meteor
By installing, you accept licenses for the packages.

meteor v0.0.5 [Approved]
meteor package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
The package meteor wants to run 'chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
Note: If you don't run this script, the installation will fail.
Note: To confirm automatically next time, use '-y' or consider:
choco feature enable -n allowGlobalConfirmation
Do you want to run the script?([Y]es/[A]ll - yes to all/[N]o/[P]rint): y

Downloading meteor 64 bit
from 'https://packages.meteor.com/bootstrap-link?arch=os.windows.x86_64'
ERROR: The remote file either doesn't exist, is unauthorized, or is forbidden for url 'https://packages.meteor.com/bootstrap-link?arch=os.windows.x86_64'. Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The operation has timed out"
This package is likely not broken for licensed users - see https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/features/private-cdn.
The install of meteor was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\meteor\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
See log for details.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures

- meteor (exited 404) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\meteor\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
  See log for details.

Answer (score 0):

Installation via chocolatey is deprecated. You can now install Meteor on windows via NPM:

```
npm install -g meteor
```

More detailed info on installation in the docs:

https://docs.meteor.com/install.html

If you have issues due to restricted internet access please read on this issue:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/11330